# Exercises for strained knee?

Tags: exercise, injury, knee, sprain-strain-twist

I am only 18 and I have injured my knee by doing squats. I have stopped them, I went to my doctor and he checked my x rays and said everything is normal. He did tell me that I have strained my knee and he gave me a bonsalic tablet. I completed my course but the pain still persists. He asked me to continue the medication, but is there also any exercise for this?

Comment: No painkillers at all, no recommendation on what to do, just those bonsalic pills? You might really want to switch doctors.

Comment: he initially gave me walker 10 which seems to be a pain killer,after completing my course he asked me to stop it,since my pain has reduced.